# jQuery sortable with overflow: hidden; between two lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two lists in which using jQuery sortable i can move the items between them.

```
$( '#productsList, #orderList' )
.sortable({connectWith: '.containerDiv'})
.disableSelection();
```

However I run into a problem when i want to use custom scroll bar and set `overflow:hidden;` on the two lists. I want them to be with `max-height:400px`. 
If i set overflow hidden i cant see the items after i drag them outside of one div, If i dont set hidden the list will have default scroll bar.
Can anyone suggest a solution.

thanks

Comment: If you could get a working model on JSFiddle, that would help a lot.

Comment: here is a simple representation http://jsfiddle.net/cCDcQ/
as you can see dragging the text out will be hidden and i need to make it visible (i use custom scrollbar which requires overflow: hidden;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove the style `position:relative` from your lists is seems to work as you want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/cCDcQ/2/

**Edit:**

I would have thought that using the appendTo option would fix this issue and I was right. After a bit more fiddling, I got it to work. This way, you can keep the `position:relative` if you need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/cCDcQ/4/

Comment: thanks man, this is it, can u clarify what happens with helper:"clone"?
does it creates a clone and hides the original element?
i tried appendTo but it didnt seem to work without it and helper:"clone" is nowhere documented.

Comment: Sure, clone just makes an exact copy of the draggable *when it is being dragged* and removes the original (temporarily). In this case, it appends it to the .demo element. While inspecting the DOM, it looks as though just `appendTo` doesn't actually append anything without `helper:clone`.

Comment: i had some jquery animations on the elements and they dont play after moving the elements, its probably the clone problem. Is there option instead of clone to be exact element?
I just checked andd its same even without position:relative; so its not the cloned object problem

Comment: That would be `helper:"original"` which is the default behavior. It seems like a bug to me that appendTo doesn't work as expected.

Comment: man you nailed it again. How can i give u million points hah.

thanks mate

Comment: so there is another problem now

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/3056/

i am using custom scroll, the problem is when i drag out the item it is invisible, with helper:"original" doesnt work and i dont want to use helper:"clone" because the animation wont work on drop.

Comment: Try making another question, reference this one but be as descriptive of the immediate problem you have. Someone should be able to help. If not, I'll see if I can find your question a bit later.

Comment: Done
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796303/jquery-sortable-and-custom-scroll-bar

Comment: Really help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this ticket is somewhat dated, but I had ran into the same issue while using my custom scrollbar solution and attempting to drag between Sortable's with overflow hidden.  After adding code to fix-up Sortable to work with my Scrollpane, I noticed what appeared to be an omission for the appendTo functionality.

The code for *appendTo* only appends the helper to the target if it doesn't exist in the DOM.  That's why the clone options works for some (but not for all and I won't go into that here).  The key to fixing it was to add this code toward the end of the *_mouseStart* function of the widget:

```
if (!this.helper.parent().is(this.appendTo)) {
    this.helper.detach().appendTo(this.appendTo);
    // update position
    this.offset.parent = this._getParentOffset();
}
```

Note that *this.appendTo* is set-up earlier in the function:

```
this.appendTo = $( o.appendTo !== "parent" ?
        o.appendTo :
        this.currentItem.parent() );
```

With this fix in place, I specified an *appendTo* that targeted the div that contained both Sortable's and ceased to have the overflow issue.

The complete fix-up, including other flow fixes, is available in the scrollsortable JS file for the jQuery-UI-ScrollPane available here:  https://github.com/borgboyone/jQuery-UI-ScrollPane.

Cheers!