# jQuery sortable and custom scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using custom scrollbar in my webapp but I have the following problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/3056

As you can see when you drag an item out of the list it is invisible.
I need to make it visible and to be original item because I have animation triggers bind to it.

You can understand more of what I am trying to do if you check this: 
[jQuery sortable with overflow: hidden; between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772129/jquery-sortable-with-overflow-hidden-between-two-lists)

Comment: Hey do you need item0 to stay outside like you showed in demo? I might know what is causing the disappearing of the item, let me if you cool to move both as a scrollable lists.

Comment: item0 is in a separate list, i need to exchange items between two lists and both have custom scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/3089/

This is just about the same fix as the last one so I'll try to break this down and explain a bit for ya:

The appendTo option is set to "BODY" so that it is not within the confines of your list's dimensions and hidden when it is dragged outside of them.

Because the the draggable is appended to the body when it's being dragged, it's no longer part of your `UL` style. This is why I added the extra classes to the `LI`s

Comment: i know but the problem is when i use clone the animation doesnt work and when i use original i still cant see the element out of the list

Comment: I guess I'm not sure. I see an animation still on the scroll bar with my script. I don't see the difference. Can you clarify the problem a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

I know this ticket is somewhat dated, but I had ran into the same issue while using my custom scrollbar solution and attempting to drag between Sortable's with overflow hidden.  After adding code to fix-up Sortable to work with my Scrollpane, I noticed what appeared to be an omission for the appendTo functionality.

The code for *appendTo* only appends the helper to the target if it doesn't exist in the DOM.  That's why the clone options works for some (but not for all and I won't go into that here).  The key to fixing it was to add this code toward the end of the *_mouseStart* function of the widget:

```
if (!this.helper.parent().is(this.appendTo)) {
    this.helper.detach().appendTo(this.appendTo);
    // update position
    this.offset.parent = this._getParentOffset();
}
```

Note that *this.appendTo* is set-up earlier in the function:

```
this.appendTo = $( o.appendTo !== "parent" ?
        o.appendTo :
        this.currentItem.parent() );
```

The complete fix-up, including other flow fixes, is available in the scrollsortable JS file for the jQuery-UI-ScrollPane available here:  https://github.com/borgboyone/jQuery-UI-ScrollPane.  (Note: This fix-up has been made available to the jQuery-UI project via pull-request.)

Cheers!